# How to Commit/Rollback stored procedure based on return value in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a javascript stored procedure that return boolean. I want to be able to call this stored procedure inside a transaction and test the return value before committing the transaction.

```html
BEGIN;
SET result = CALL my_stored_proc();

IF $result = true 
COMMIT;
ELSE
ROLLBACK;
```

The stored procedure will return false if there is an exception or if there is some missing values based on business logic.

How do I achieve this in Snowflake?

---

EDIT:
I tried the following and it did not work. The transaction remains open and the statements executed inside the stored proc are not rolled back until an explicit ROLLBACK statement is issued.

```
USE COMMON;


CREATE TABLE LOG
(
LOG_ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT PK_LOG_ID PRIMARY KEY,
LOG_LEVEL VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
LOGGER VARCHAR (500) NOT NULL,
MESSAGE VARCHAR NOT NULL,
EXCEPTION VARCHAR NULL,
APPLICATION_NAME VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
LOGGED_ON DATETIME DEFAULT TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) NOT NULL,
LOGGED_BY VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT CURRENT_USER() NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_TRANSACTION() 
RETURNS VARCHAR 
LANGUAGE javascript 
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
snowflake.execute({sqlText:`
INSERT
            INTO
                COMMON.LOG (LOG_LEVEL, LOGGER, MESSAGE, EXCEPTION, APPLICATION_NAME)
            VALUES ('DEBUG', 'TEST_TRANSACTION', 'This is a test transaction.', '', 'DATA LOADER'); 
`});
snowflake.execute({sqlText:`
INSERT
            INTO
                COMMON.LOG (LOG_LEVEL, LOGGER, MESSAGE, EXCEPTION, APPLICATION_NAME)
            VALUES ('DEBUG', 'TEST_TRANSACTION', 'This message should not be in the logs.', '', 'DATA LOADER'); 
`});

throw 'Test error'
$$
;
-- Run the next 3 lines as a batch
BEGIN;
CALL COMMON.TEST_TRANSACTION(); -- This Fails
COMMIT; -- Commit is NOT executed

SELECT * FROM COMMON.LOG WHERE LOGGER = 'TEST_TRANSACTION'; -- The insert is successful & the transaction is still OPEN
```

How do I rollback the statements executed inside the stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that you CAN issue transaction control commands (BEGIN, COMMIT, ROLLBACK) inside a stored procedure. I can being the transaction, check the return value inside the stored procedure and decide to COMMIT or ROLLBACK.

Someone should update the snowflake documentation.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_TRANSACTION(result BOOLEAN) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN NOT NULL 
LANGUAGE javascript 
EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
$$
snowflake.execute({sqlText:`BEGIN;`});

snowflake.execute({sqlText:`
INSERT
            INTO
                COMMON.LOG (LOG_LEVEL, LOGGER, MESSAGE, EXCEPTION, APPLICATION_NAME)
            VALUES ('DEBUG', 'TEST_TRANSACTION', 'This is a test transaction.', '', 'DATA LOADER'); 
`});
snowflake.execute({sqlText:`
INSERT
            INTO
                COMMON.LOG (LOG_LEVEL, LOGGER, MESSAGE, EXCEPTION, APPLICATION_NAME)
            VALUES ('DEBUG', 'TEST_TRANSACTION', 'This message should not be in the logs.', '', 'DATA LOADER'); 
`});

if ( RESULT ) { snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "COMMIT" }) } 
    else {
        snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "ROLLBACK" }) };

return true;
$$
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend reading through this document as it offers several examples and methods to do what you are asking.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#transaction-management

Comment: @user:12178980 I have read through the entire page and there is no mention of testing the return value to either commit or rollback. My question is very specific. How do I ROLLBACK the transaction if the stored proc returns FALSE. I know that I can get the return value like this - SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) but what do I do after that, how do I tell snowflake to rollback if the value is FALSE.

Comment: I realize that this article doesn't answer the specific question you are asking, but it does tell you how to handle a transaction and a stored procedure that fails.  It just doesn't do it in the same way that you are requesting.  Why not change your SP to the way that this article suggests and handle the rollback in that manner, rather than returning a boolean of "FALSE" and trying to handle it in a way that isn't the recommended way?

Comment: Could you please point me to where it shows how to handle a transaction and a stored procedure that fails. I am really struggling to find that on the page that you shared. I cannot issue the rollback statement inside the stored proc, can I? Or do I have to throw an error from the stored proc for Snowflake to stop execution and leave the transaction in a flux?

Comment: BEGIN;
W;
CALL MyProcedure();   -- executes X and Y
Z;
COMMIT;

In this example, if the SP fails, the DML inside of SP is rolled back since the statement fails.  If it succeeds, it is committed, since the script is allowed to continue to the COMMIT.

Comment: Note the comments in the article if you are doing any DDL inside your SP, which would then need to use a TRY/CATCH that undoes what you did.  That is also outlined in the article.