# How to Commit/Rollback a transaction based on the result of the previous query in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a transaction like this

```
BEGIN;

...

SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())); -- Returns TRUE/FALSE

+----------------+
| Result         |
|----------------|
| FALSE          |
+----------------+

-- If TRUE
COMMIT;

-- If FALSE
-- ROLLBACK;
```

How do I ROLLBACK in this case based on the result of the previous query which is "FALSE"? I want to automate this script and not make a decision at runtime myself.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Commit/Rollback stored procedure based on return value in Snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132365/how-to-commit-rollback-stored-procedure-based-on-return-value-in-snowflake)

Comment: My sample code works as expected, you can test it by yourself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can create a stored procedure and execute commit or rollback based on argument:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE commit_or_rollback( result BOOLEAN ) 
returns BOOLEAN
language javascript
AS
$$
    if ( RESULT ) { snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "COMMIT" }) } 
    else {
        snowflake.execute( {sqlText: "ROLLBACK" }) };
    return RESULT;        
$$
;
```

So your script will be something like this:

```
BEGIN

...

CALL commit_or_rollback(  SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID())) );
```

A test case:

```
BEGIN;

SELECT CURRENT_TRANSACTION();

+-----------------------+
| CURRENT_TRANSACTION() |
+-----------------------+
| 1591113827577         |
+-----------------------+

CALL commit_or_rollback( ( SELECT TRUE ) ); 

+--------------------+
| COMMIT_OR_ROLLBACK |
+--------------------+
| TRUE               |
+--------------------+

SELECT CURRENT_TRANSACTION();
```

The last command returns NULL. I can also see the COMMIT is executed in query history.

Comment: As per the documentation COMMIT/ROLLBACK statements are not allowed inside stored procedures. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html#restrictions-on-stored-procedures

Comment: Thanks for heads up, but I can see it executes commit statement. Have you checked it? I added a test case to see it works.

Comment: Ah! Thanks a lot. I tried it out and it does work. It looks like I can even BEGIN the transaction inside the stored procedure. Someone should update the documentation in that case.